# Bootstrap lists with links don't line up with lists in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a base.html file that loads Bootstrap from CDN and then I have a few custom css styles in base.css.  However, in the navbar I have some weird vertical alignment, where one type of element, `.navbar-nav > li` sits at the top of the navbar compared to `.navbar-nav > li > a`.  My django html template looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#"><img style="margin-top: -10px;" src={% static "classroom/images/vsb-logo.png" %}></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href={% url 'admin:index' %}>Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href={% url 'classroom:blocklist' %}>Classlist</a></li>
        <li><a href={% url 'classroom:random' %}>Randomize</a></li>
        <li>{{request.user.username}}</li>
        <li><a href={% url 'account_logout' %}>Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I have base.css superseding the bootstrap css. However, I'm not able to find the style attributes that are making the `<li>{{request.user.username}}</li>` style sit higher than the links with the anchor tags, such as `<li><a href={% url 'admin:index' %}>Admin</a></li>`

I have given the following styles to both selectors and I've checked in the browser developer tools that that these are the same for both:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I can hack this and change my username line to:

```
<li><a href="#">{{request.user.username}}</a></li>
```

but I'd like to find out what is causing this this misalignment.
[Here is a live page with the problem](http://www.dryfly.ca/base.html)

Comment: Post the situation on a live server so that someone can help debug it for you through developer tools.  Beyond that...we're all guessing.

Comment: Original question is edited to include a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer**

The reason why your text "Doug W" appears higher than its sibling counter parts (the anchor links), is because you are compounding a `padding-top:15px` value in base.css.

**base.css at line 20**

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    ...
}
```

Here, you are essentially saying, make each of your nav-bar li elements have a padding-top of 15px, and if there is an anchor link inside of them, compound that rule again...but this time on the anchor links too.

Sense "Doug W" does not have an anchor link wrapped around it, its not following out with both padding-top adjustments.  It's only impacted by `padding-top:15px` for `.navbar-default .navbar-nav li`, **not** for `.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a`.  This is why "Doug W" stands out.

**The long answer**

You have 3 files controlling the padding-top ratio for your nav-bar items:

**navbar.less at line 266** - from CDN

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top:10px
    ...
}
```

**navs.less at line 23** - from CDN

```
.nav>li>a {
    ...
    padding:10px 15px;
}
```

**base.css at line 20** - Your custom styelsheet

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li, .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    ...
}
```

Based on the link you are providing, it looks like you are concerned with `Doug W` being higher than your other sibling links.  Try wrapping the text `Doug W` in an anchor element like so...

```
<a href="#">Doug W</a>
```

or wrap it in a `<p>` element like so...

```
<p>Doug W</p>
```

If you decide to wrap it in a `<p>` element, that add the following CSS rule set to your style-sheet:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li p {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

or just do this...

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li p {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In conclusion, when it comes to placement and position of elements, anchor links and text fields, use CSS to control it all.  Don't leave anything unwrapped or unattained.

Comment: Yes, wrapping it with a tag like <a> will solve the problem. But my question is why is the Doug W sitting higher? As best as I can tell, the ... <li> tag has the same properties as the ...<Li> <a> tag. I would like to know why they don’t appear the same.

Comment: Understood, I just updated my answer to help shed some light on whats going on

Comment: OK I think I have it.  It's not just that they all have the same padding, it's that wrapping the line with <a> give it an additional element and an additional padding.

Comment: Yes your are correct.  That goes for any element we put in this position.

Answer (score 0):

Your misalignment issues are caused by `.navbar-nav>li>a` css rule. It has a `padding: 15px`, that is not applied to your 4th element because it's not an anchor tag.
You can try moving that css rule to apply to all list items, like so `.navbar-nav>li`

Comment: I forgot to upload the css file when moving files online. I have the css there now. Both the li and li>a items now have the same padding, but the li item is higher.